# Apply sound setting changes

Tags: linux-mint, audio

My sound is not working at all (on computer speakers or 3.5mm jack head phones) which i believe is caused by HDA Intel HDMI being the default output and not HDA Intel PCH.

So i changed the out put to HDA Intel PCH under the output tab in the sound preferences window. I could not find any apply-button so i just closed the window, still no sound. I go back to sound preferences and discover that the change i made had not been applied (its still checked as HDA Intel HDMI). How do i apply the changes in the sound preferences window?

In the window below you can see the desired setting i want to use. Unfortunately this change will not be applied apperantly.

[image: What i want to do]

Edit: my desktop is in my native language swedish, but i hope you can understand what i want to do despite of this.

I am using linux mint.